# Three.js Linewidth Workaround

Tags: three.js, line, angle

I am currently working and struggling with three.js and the linewidth-ability. I am fully aware, that the native version is not working anymore because of WebGL and ANGLE. Also I cannot use the `CanvasRenderer` instead of the `WebGLRenderer`.

So what I actually do, is loading a box-mesh with materials from a blender exported JSON, that shows a simple cube for the moment. Now I need to add a border to each face with a LineWidth greater than 1.

I found the `MeshLine` library (https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine) and tried to solve it with the library. But for now, it is only adjusting the lineWidth to the vertices in the wireframe and not only the edges of my cube, like I wanted it to be, because i cannot use `THREE.EdgesGeometry`.

```
const line = new MESHLINE.MeshLine();
line.setGeometry(houseGeometry);

const material = new MESHLINE.MeshLineMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color(borderColor), lineWidth: 0.10 });
const border = new THREE.Mesh(houseGeometry, material);
```

I am new to the 3D-World and three.js, but there need to be a solution for doing things like a simple border to an object, because it's a very essential Task of a design, right?

Maybe I just need another approach to do what I want.

I am very grateful for every answer.

Comment: See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/11349 and https://mattdesl.github.io/webgl-wireframes/app/

Comment: Does the second approach use barycentric coordinates? I like your solution a lot.

Comment: line width limits have nothing to do with ANGLE. Even OpenGL since v3 disallows sizes other than 1

Comment: Hey did you find something?